# How can I invoke a Confluence Macro when importing pages from a text file

Tags: html, confluence, text-styling

I have some text files where each text file represents a page.

Now these pages contains text along with some html content which is not getting parsed while import into confluence.

---

Example text file

== Title of the page ==

< center> You are in a test page < /center>

Some points to remember:
* This is a test page.
* The confluence version I am using is 4.2
* I need some macros to work when the page gets imported to Confluence.

---

The page in confluence is imported as follows:

## Title of the page

< center> You are in a test page < /center>

Some points to remember:

- This is a test page.
- The confluence version I am using is 4.2
- I need some macros to work when the page gets imported to Confluence.

---

The  tag is not getting converted to the respective behavior. Need some help on how to do this.

There might be some format which can be used so that the {html} macro gets invoked and  tag behaves as it should.

I have tried using {html}< center>Text< /center>{html} but it doesn't work that way.

Any help would be helpful regarding this.

Comment: Are you looking for a ready made solution or would you be willing to make your own macro to achieve this?

Comment: How are you importing this? Using the universal wiki converter? Or some other way?

Comment: Using Universal wiki converter